# DirectX Managed Pool

Tags: c++, fonts, directx, directx-9

I am writing a plugin for an existent C++ DirectX9 application. Everything was working fine until they decided to switch to IDirect3DDevice9Ex for performance reasons.

Now I get the 
"D3DPOOL_MANAGED is not valid with IDirect3DDevice9Ex" error when using "D3DXCreateFontA" to render text.

Question: Is there some workaround to draw text while using IDirect3DDevice9Ex, or some good library that allows me to draw text without using managed textures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since i don't know a good answer, maybe this is the same question with more and better answers:

[IDirect3DDevice9Ex and D3DPOOL_MANAGED?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7993/idirect3ddevice9ex-and-d3dpool-managed)

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

A manage pool keeps a copy of the resource in system memory. This allows the process to release the graphics device to other programs and then be able to recreate any lost assets using the copy in system memory.

To resolve this, try using a centralized resource cache that will dump all your resources on device lost and then recreate them when the device is recovered.

Comment: Not really helpful. The "D3DXCreateFont" is closed source I cannot manipulate it...